# Keras - Sample weight and ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

Currently, sample weight is available in ImageDataGenerator.flow() but not in ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory().

I was wondering if someone found a work around to use it with flow_from_directory?

I have hundred of thousands of images in 46 classes. The images come from two different sources. One in which I have 100% confidence in the labelling and the second one in which I have less confidence.

I m looking for a way to tell the model to give less attention to the source in which I have less confidence. I think that giving more less weight to the samples coming from the source would be good start. But I can't figure out how to set the sample_weight in a flow_from_directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another method provided by keras.ImageDataGenerator named ***flow_from_dataframe*** which allows you to define in a dataframe your data sources and add some metada like the weight for each file thanks to the ***weight_col*** keyword parameter.

Here is the init function :

```
flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, directory=None, x_col='filename', y_col='class', weight_col=None,
    target_size=(256, 256), color_mode='rgb', classes=None,
    class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=None,
    save_to_dir=None, save_prefix='', save_format='png', subset=None,
    interpolation='nearest', validate_filenames=True, **kwargs
)
```

And the complete documentation : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe

Comment: Thank you. That exactly what I was looking for. I should have read the documentation :)